# Web service, dynamic address in WSDL address

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I'm very new to web services, so sorry if I write a lot of wrong things...

I created a few java classes and generated the wsdl, so I have a bottom-up web service.
I deployed everything (in an EAR) and called

```
  http://localhost:7159/chc2/services/WebServiceManager
```

to invoke the web service. It works, I obtain the results.

The problem is that I need to deploy the application on other servers, and obviously the first part of the url, the local ip won't be the same.

That url is declared by me in the WSDL with:

```
<wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:7159/chc2/services/WebServiceManager"/>
```

My question is: there is a way to get the ip part of the link in a dynamic way in the .wsdl?
I've found on the net some ways to do it in Java, but I'm directly calling the .wsdl, not passing through java...I guess if there is a way to do that in the .wsdl.

The other configuration files I have are server-config.wsdd and web.xml.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some application servers will allow you to submit Web services containing WSDLs with dummy address location:

```
<soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL"/>
```

Upon deployment, they will replace this value with actual URL! [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net) supports this feature for sure (actually, I think that you can put whatever you want in address location value, Glassfish will replace it automatically), and according to [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/6/WebServices_Guide/en-US/html/chap_JBossWS-JAX-WSTools.html#JBossWS-JAX-WSTools_Client_Side), [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org) also supports this 'feature'. HTH.

Comment: That's very interesting, even if I tried right now and it doesn't work with weblogic 10.3.5 (I was hoping very much for this to work!). Thank you very much for your answer :)

Comment: If you get an NPE as like 
`java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisEndpoint.calculateEndpointURL(AxisEndpoint.java:186)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.setPortAddress(AxisService.java:1594)
...`
That's Apache-Axis2:
`org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.setPortAddress(javax.wsdl.Definition definition, java.lang.String requestIP)`
`...
 if (existingAddress == null
  || existingAddress.equals("REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL")) {
  // ...`

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, your issue is: when you deploy the webservice on other servers how would you call the webservice?

Your servers obviously are part of nodes/a cluster. On a Java EE application server, for example on WebSphere, `plugin-config.xml` is where you can configure the incoming/outgoing http ports.

The IBM HTTP Web Server will be configured with your Application server through `plugin-config.xml`. This will expose your webserice as http://:port/webserviceURI. This is the URL which you will use to call the webservice independent of the application server's IP.

Comment: Yes (thanks for the explanation), but the problem is that to call it I should define the port in "wsdlsoap:address location" in a dynamic way, so that it can be deployed on different servers without having to manually change it on the .wsdl(in the example I've written at the beginning it's obviously declared in a static way)! I hope I've explained myself :D

Answer (score 1):

Generate wsdl through XSD dynamically using sws tag placing in [servler-name]-servlet.xml

```
<sws:dynamic-wsdl
        id="getemployeeDetails"
        portTypeName="EmpService"
        locationUri="/empService"
        targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/">
        <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/employee.xsd"/>

    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>
```

In this way you can have the url as dynamic when hosted on server

Regards

Anshul

Answer (score 1):

this is the way we can dynamically change the wsdl location url

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class WsdlDynamicPath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            changePath();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | 
 TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void changePath() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerException{
        String filepath = "path to wsdl\\demo.wsdl"; //Give your wsdl file path
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

        Node address= doc.getElementsByTagName("soap:address").item(0);

        NamedNodeMap attr = address.getAttributes();
        Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("location");
        nodeAttr.setTextContent("new path to wsdl");

        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    }

}
```